# How do you store node_modules in git?

Tags: git, version-control, npm, node-modules

There are lots of answers to the question 'Why should I store node_modules in source control?', but I can't find any explaining how.

- Option 1) Commit them as part of your repo.

  - This is easy
  - The files won't change much as we specify specific version numbers of our dependencies (e.g. 5.2.19) to avoid cascading failures when a patch update contains a bug
  - The disadvantage is it makes your repository huge
- Option 2) Use git submodules

  - There are lots of articles on the internet called 'why you shouldn't use submodules' so I didn't even look into this option
- Option 3) Use git [subtree](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/)

  - The advantage of this is you can share dependencies among repositories, and you keep external code out of your repositories
  - The disadvantage is that it's m[ore complicated](https://medium.com/@v/git-subtrees-a-tutorial-6ff568381844#.p3m883j93), with more sequences of commands to remember and do every time you need to change something in node_modules

So far option 1 has my vote as it's fool-proof

Is there a better way? What is best practice?